# Converting a human into 3d

Tags: 3d

This might not be completely relevant to stackoverflow but I have no better site where to post this.

We have gotten a request to develop something that can get a real human into a 3d application including textures.

Now I have no idea how to handle this as we have no previous experience. So is this possible and if it's possible what kind of things would we need ?

Edit: Just some additional info, this is an idea a teacher at my school came up with and he wants it to be able to scan people in, in a few minutes. So the most viable thing seems to be the use of multiple camera's possibly in combination with a green/blue screen.

Comment: I guess game developers and Hollywood CGI guys have tools for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need textures, you'll need at least one camera. You might want to install several cameras and use [stereo vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_stereo_vision) techniques to get the 3d information. You could also fuse one camera with measurements of one or more laser scanners or Time of Flight Cameras (yielding distance images).

If you also need motion models you should take a look at what sports games do (EA Sports, Pro Evolution Soccer...). As far as I know they record motion based on marks placed on people.

Maybe this helps as a first start.

Comment: It seems that this will be the way to go (See the edit), but I still have doubts whether this is doable in a live environment

Comment: what aro you going to do with the data? Are you trying to get motion models as well or just a static 3d model of a person?

Comment: Hmm motion models would be nice but I guess that would make it even more challenging than it already is. And for that stereoscopic vision techniques won't suffice.

Answer (score 2):

There is a company in Glasgow, Scotland that have a lot of experience with this:
[Dimensional Imaging Ltd.](http://www.di3d.com/)

Their demos look impressive and I know a lot of original research on this has been done in Glasgow.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will pass it on to the project members

Answer (score 1):

In principle you need to use a [3D scanner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_scanner) to capture the 3D structure of the person. I have no experience with these, but they are commercially available.

For the surface, you could just photograph the person, then use software to create textures (you'd need to remove perspective distortion etc.). Then assemble everything in a 3D software.

That's just a *very* rough outline; the process is rather complex.

If I may ask: How did you get such a complex project with "no previous experience"? Seems rather unusual...

Comment: It is indeed rather ambitious but if we succeed at least we've gained a lot of experience in the field of 3d